# Is there a better way to calculate π in one line?

Tags: python, pi

I've written solution of how to calculate pi number in python in one line:

```
def calc_pi(n=100):
    return 4.0 * sum([1 for i in range(n) if hypot(random(), random()) < 1]) / (n + 1)
```

I would like to know if there is a better solution for that and how to make it simpler?

P.S. I want to practice complex one-line functions, list comprehensions etc. Monte Carlo method is just an example.

Comment: What makes a solution "better"? This is one of the slowest methods to calculate pi in the first place, so just about anything will be faster.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, questions should be not only answerable, but also *practical* to be on-topic on StackOverflow. Focusing on terseness over other factors is innately impractical, as is ignoring an optimized standard-library alternative; questions that seek the shortest possible implementation of an algorithm without regard to other considerations are code-golf puzzles, and belong on [codegolf.se] (within the [bounds described by the Help Center there](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: `return 4.0 * sum(hypot(random(), random()) < 1 for _ in range(n)) / (n + 1)`

Comment: As per the edit you want to practice one-liners -- sounds like [codegolf.se] *really is* the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 4 * atan(1)

```
sum([1 for i in range(n) if hypot(random(), random()) < 1]) / n
```

will tend to `atan(1)` for large `n`, so you might as well calculate it directly:

```
>>> import math
>>> 4 * math.atan(1)
3.141592653589793
```

It at least looks like your formula and doesn't explicitely use `math.pi`.

By the way, I don't think you should divide by `n+1` but by `n`. `range(n)` has `n` elements.

## Code improvements

Also, you don't need to create a huge list just to calculate its sum. `sum` works fine with a generator.

I guess your `hypot` function uses `sqrt`. No need for it, since you're comparing to `1` and `sqrt(1) == 1`:

```
>>> from random import random
>>> n = 10000000
>>> 4.0 * sum(1 for i in range(n) if (random()**2 + random()**2) <= 1) / n
3.1418616
```

As mentioned by @Blender, you could also sum booleans:

```
>>> 4.0 * sum((random()**2 + random()**2) <= 1 for _ in range(n)) / n
3.1417656
```

## Other series

Finally, there are better methods. This one is slow-ish, but it's concise and deterministic:

```
>>> 4 * sum(1.0/(2*i + 1)*(-1)**i for i in range(1000000))
3.1415916535897743
```

There are others, [faster methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/series-that-converge-to-pi-quickly).

Comment: drop the `[]`: `sum(1 for i in range(n) if hypot(random(), random()) < 1) / n`, no need to build an extra list. also beware of python 2: you would end up with 0 (integer division)

Comment: `sum(hypot(random(), random()) < 1 for _ in range(n))` works just as well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you're right, thanks.

Comment: @Eric Duminil I agree with n+1

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is:

```
import math; print(math.pi)
```

Calculating pi is pointless since it will have a maximum precision of whatever type you use, and `math.pi` will be just as accurate.

One way you could make it simpler is by removing the list comprehension and just making it a generator expression:

```
def calc_pi2(n=100):
    return 4.0 * sum(1 for i in range(n) if hypot(random(), random()) < 1) / (n + 1)
```

And if you're simply intending to save characters, this will also work:

```
def calc_pi3(n=100):
 return 4*sum(hypot(random(),random())<1for _ in range(n))/(n+1)
```

Comment: haha, ofc I forgot to write that I want to use Monte Carlo method :D

Comment: But, I want to practice python one line methods on Monte Carlo method. I'd never put my function into serious program. I'd change description - it's not so clear.

Comment: Why would you want to practice complex one line functions? You realize that goes directly against the Zen of Python, "simple is better than complex", right?

Comment: ofc I know, but I could do this in simple for with if and variables declaration but this is C/C++ style. In this case complex means, that it's not a simple getter and setter. I wanted to convert 6-9 lines of C++ code into one line of python. Btw, thanks for your attention, and help.

Comment: `/n`, not `/(n+1)`